# Count of range on datetime in MySql

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I want to group table entries for each `userId` only if they are consecutive entries in the table. 
I have a table like this.

```
id userId      transactionTime

1  1           2016-04-13 22:15:44
2  1           2016-04-13 22:40:22
3  1           2016-04-13 22:41:34
4  2           2016-04-13 22:41:34
5  2           2016-04-13 22:42:25
6  1           2016-04-13 23:43:55
```

Expected Result:

```
userId    count
1         3
2         2
1         1
```

Thanks :)

**Update:**
The transactionTime is ordered in asc. Considering this, we can check the consecutive occurence of same userId and make it a single entry with number of counts.

Consider this, `userId=1` occurs three consecutive times from `id=1,2,3` this will be first result with `userId=1 and count=3`. Similarly at `id=4 and 5` `userId` is `2` which will be second row in the result with `userId=1` and `count=2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables for this kind of thing:

```
select userId, count(*)
from (
    select @g:=case when userId=@lastuserId then @g else @g+1 end AS grp,
           @lastuserId:=userId AS userId
    from test1, (select@lastuserId:=0, @g:=0) vars
    order by transactionTime
) groups
group by grp, userId
order by grp
```

Comment: Thanks... Which is a better option? Whether to manipulate data in java after fetching initial table or just run the complex query you've provided.?

Comment: Currently, it's taking 92-130 seconds to run the query.